# Upgrading to Spark 1.5.0 on Ambari

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using the Hortonworks release which uses Spark 1.3.

When I ran my app using Spark API 1.5 it failed, but switching to 1.3 worked.

There are new features in 1.5 that I want to use on the server but apparently this is not possible without upgrading it.

How do I upgrade Spark from 1.3 to 1.5 on Ambari?